With Jdk 17 upgrade from 8 and Primefaces from 8 to 12, Jakarta @Pattern validations not working
With Jdk 17 upgrade from 8 and Primefaces from 8 to 12, Jakarta @Pattern validations not working .
Any suggestions ?
.
Fyi, Jakarta validation dependency and Hibernate dependency added.
Expecting @Pattern regex should work, but not working from DTO object field validation
